# SharePoint 2010 unable to resolve usernames in peoplepicker

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, people-picker

In a SharePoint 2010 Foundation environment, I am experiencing issues when attempting to edit a list element. It seems to be caused by peoplepicker fields, but can't verify this for sure. We are using windows authentication in classic mode.

In newform I am able to resolve users and save the list item without difficulty. In editform however there is some bizarre behavior:

- on some list elements I am able to resolve the usernames of additional users, on other list elements the same usernames won't resolve at all.
- when inside the editform of a list element where user names resolve, pressing save will fail. No error is presented in the form, but you see SharePoint is working, trying to resolve the username. If I wait long enough I will be presented with a "Error: An unexpected error has occured" message
- on some elements when I click the edit button, the form will not appear at all. It will just start working, and then give the same error as above: "Error: An unexpected error has occured"

In ULS I see an error message "User does not exist or is not unique". I have attempted some of the suggestions from Google when searching for that error message.

[habaneroconsulting.com:](http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique#.VqXVa_krJaQ) SiteUserAccountDirectoryPath does not have a value, and after my understanding this means that it will search the entire domain.

[Microsoft Technet:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/51ed366a-5c1b-499d-acca-f9892645aba4/the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique?forum=sharepointadminprevious)  Made sure the application pool account has access to registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure

[Microsoft Technet:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/31adb5f6-722b-458f-9888-1e3e3c6271b9/sharepoint-people-picker-with-forms-auth?forum=sharepointadminprevious) wildcard for people picker in web.config is in place

I have also thought about the possibility that the editform itself is broken so I have generated a new one using SharePoint Designer, but we still have the same issue.

I must mention that the environment in question has been moved to new servers, and the users have new domains and usernames. The migration was done using PowerShell where I looped through all site collections, got the user object by Get-SPUser and then

```
Move-SPUser -Identity $oldUser -NewAlias "i:0#.w|<newDomain>\<newUserName> -IgnoreSID
```

Anyone have an idea how I fix this?